# Uninstall more than one thing at once

Tags: windows-7, uninstall

Is there a way to do a "batch uninstall" where you select the 30 or so programs that you want uninstalled, and it opens all of there uninstallers at once, and lets you do it that way? If not, is there a way to queue them?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Batch uninstall Windows programs with Absolute Uninstaller

http://www.glarysoft.com/products/utilities/absolute-uninstaller/

Comment: Incredibly buggy software :(

Comment: I agree with Evgeniy. This program is extremely buggy. Please do not install this crap.

Answer (score 2):

Using a third-party tool, like many Uninstallers available, is the easiest way to achieve this. Alternatively you could script uninstall operations through Windows PowerShell. But, as you would expect, this process is more involving.

There's otherwise no Windows 7 specific feature that will let you do batch uninstallion of software.